# Convert string to utf-8 unicode in ColdFusion

Tags: unicode, coldfusion

I need to convert a string to a UTF8 encoded format and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is there any function within ColdFusion to convert a string into UTF-8, such as on this [website](https://mothereff.in/utf-8)?

For example, typing in *"stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"* into the above website gives the result:

> \x73\x74\x61\x63\x6B\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x2F\x61\x73\x6B

I am not very familiar with encoding, however my instructions were to encode a string to UTF-8. The example I was given gave an encoded result of the below for example.

> /re/r/434/t//4r3/t434/4t/t3/3/4t/43tt/53/

I am not sure if this is a real representation of an encoded string or if it was just typed out to give a visual example. Is there a format that looks like that? And is it different than the format from the first example?

Thank you!

Comment: (Edit) *RE:  Example I was given gave an encoded result of the below for example* Can you give us some context?  What is the source of that example? If this is for an API, can you post the URL? *RE:...such as on this website* That site chooses to display the utf-8 binary in hex. [TryCF Example](http://trycf.com/gist/dced3d873ca415f2a568f81f7ba99ed2/acf2016?theme=monokai).  Notice the results are the same, just without the leading "\x": ie `46 6F 6F 20...` instead of `\x46 \x6F \x6F \x20 ....`.

Comment: It's for the Tipalti documentation system. You can see their documentation here: https://support.tipalti.com/Content/Topics/Development/iFrames/iframe_authentication.htm

I'm trying to get the Authentication working!

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. The "encode as UTF8..." part is simply [using charsetDecode as mentioned below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39926218/104223). The C# code simply grabs the utf8 binary of the string, ie `charsetDecode(someString, "utf-8")`. If you are having trouble with the full Authentication routine, you should open a separate thread with the code you have tried, and the result.

Comment: Any luck? I have a few ideas if you have not figured it out.

Comment: Yes, the problem was actually in the timestamp, and not the string. Their documentation just wasn't very clear. All that was required in terms of encoding was that the string be in lower case and utf-8. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to hear you figured things out. Might help the next guy to run into the same problem to a) update your question and append a note about the issue with that specific API then b) post the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use a combination of [CharsetDecode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f64.html) and [CharsetEncode()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f63.html) to accomplish this.

```
<cfset my_string = "test">
<cfset binary_my_string = CharsetDecode(my_string, "ASCII")>
<cfset utf8_my_string = CharsetEncode(binary_my_string, "utf-8")>
```

You'd just need to substitute [the correct initial encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) for *"ASCII"* in my example.

Comment: This seems to just convert the string back into the initial string

Comment: Because ASCII is a subset of UTF8. It seems your real question is part of a bigger context. Like I mentioned above, best to open a new thread with the full code and results so someone can help you achieve the real goal, which is implementing an api's authentication rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset str = "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
<cfset hexStr = "">

<cfloop index="i" from="0" to="#len(str)-1#">
    <!--- Pick out each character in the string. Remember that charAt() starts at index 0. --->
    <cfset ch = str.charAt(i)>
    <!--- The decimal value of the Unicode character. ColdFusion uses the Java UCS-2 representation of Unicode characters, up to a value of 65536.  --->
    <cfset charDecVal = asc(ch)>
    <!--- The decimal value of the character, upper-casing the letters.--->
    <cfset charHexVal = uCase(formatBaseN(charDecVal,"16"))>
    <!--- Append the characters together into a Hex string, using delimiter '\x' --->
    <cfset hexStr = hexStr & "\x" & charHexVal>
</cfloop>
<cfscript>
    writeoutput(hexStr);
</cfscript>
```