# How to prevent unicode character corruption when using getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues()?

Tags: coldfusion, urlencode

We have a scenario where a page submits multiple fields with the same name. To workaround the default approach of CF to put these into a comma-delimited string, without changing application-wide, we access field values in certain places as an array using `getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues("#fieldname#")`.

The problem we are experiencing is that unicode characters submitted are being corrupted. For example `El celular que compré está averiado` in a field array comes back as the string `El celular que comprÃ© estÃ¡ averiado`. If I dump `getHTTPRequestData()` I can see the properly url encoded `El+celular+que+compr%C3%A9+est%C3%A1+averiado` is sent to the server.

Is the java string not being handled by CF correctly? Anyway to resolve this issue on a non-application-wide basis other than parsing `getHTTPRequestData().content` which we really don't want to do?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason will be because your webserver is not using utf-8 internally for its encoding of parameters. You don't get to see this normally when accessing variables by the `url` scope, because CF has already converted them for you, however you can see this difference when looking at `cgi.query_string` or at `getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues(...)`

In your case it looks like you're seeing `windows-1252` encoding. I had a similar issue around IIS7.5 - IIS8. Assuming you can't or don't want to risk trying to change your webserver configuration, this workaround should work for you:

```
webserverEncodedString = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues(fieldname);
binaryValue = CharsetDecode(webserverEncodedString, "windows-1252");
utf8EncodedString = CharsetEncode(binaryValue, "utf-8");
```

Comment: I actually came up with this resolution yesterday. Why it was happening I wasn't sure. Will check out the webserver's encoding though.

Comment: I wrote this in the comments against my code several years ago - it was on a Win 2008 R2 / IIS7.5 box: Inspiration comes from using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924847/convert-string-to-utf-8-unicode-in-coldfusion as a solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764446/problem-using-unicode-in-urls-with-cgi-path-info-in-coldfusion -alternative MS Hotfix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-a-php-application-that-depends-on-the-request-uri-server-variable-may-fail-when-a-request-whose-url-contains-utf-8-characters-is-sent-to-iis-7-5-a3055458-c109-1298-c704-30f0453a7bcb

Comment: I'm not sure at what point the utf-8 server variables option became a standard feature in IIS. I don't remember having to patch later servers.